# Opening file folder present in a FTP site in file explorer on the client-side

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ftp

I have a folder structure in FTP, that I am trying to access and open in file explorer on the client-side using javascript in my asp.net application. Using window.open("ftp://192.168.1.10/clients/112"); opens the folder in the web browser how do I make it open in the file explorer.

Comment: To clarify, you want your JavaScript to launch a specific native application outside the browser? What does this have to do with c# and asp.net?

Comment: @Chris - I am actually trying to access the ftp url in the windows file explorer from my website. But I am not able to do it. My website ( which uses asp.net c#) is hosted in our company intranet and the ftp is also setup inside the network

Answer (score -1):

The real answer is that you do not understand what you, in any way, are doing. You are trying to cross standards which is prevented inherently, but by your lack of technical knowledge, you don't know help when you see it. The part below shows ways to possibly handle it.

---

For a machine to connect to an ftp server, they need to authenticate and do so over the correct protocol. That is not the protocol that browsers use.

Now, that is not to say that I can't go in my browser, type ftp://... and see a directory. But that is totally different. Your browser switches protocols based on your url. That can't just happen when your a webpage in a clients browser.

Your web server can conduct ftp traffic though. You can read that structure and show it to your user. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229716(v=vs.110).aspx

A clever guy can make this happen. It used to be easy in flash/flex, but.. progress.

Comment: I have been taking a look at implementing the file structure for the client .But it wont fit my requirement. I am looking for a solution where I can access the ftp url like you would access a file on the network  thanks for the help